# Opening a blob storage document in _blank tab

Tags: pdf, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-blob-storage

I have a ViewModel returning a list of documents and their associated blob storage address. When the user clicks the link I want to be able to open the pdf document in another tab but using the code below I have been unable to do so.

```
<h4><a href="@document.ContentBlobURL" target="_blank">@document.Name</a></h4>
```

I have also tried:

```
<h4><a href="Url.Content(@document.ContentBlobURL)" target="_blank">@document.Name</a></h4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include Url.Content for this as it is rendering the blob storage address straight from the database

```
<h4><a href="@document.ContentBlobURL" target="_blank">@document.Name</a></h4>
```